# Flatten _metadata and extract _id key value in Spark scala from ES

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm moving data from ElasticSearch to HDFS, saving them as avro using the databrick library. **I need to have flatten data** as output, so I'm applying the following function:

```
def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
    val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)
    f.dataType match { case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName) case _ => Array(col(colName))  }  }
  )
}
```

To my data:

```
var df = sql.read.format("es").load("my-index/log").withColumnRenamed("@timestamp", "ts")
val flattened = flattenSchema(df.schema)
val renamed = flattened.map(name => col(name.toString()).as(name.toString().replace(".","_")))
df = df.select(renamed:_*)
```

This worked as a charm, until now.

Unforunately, now I have to add `_id` from the `_metadata` returned from ES. First of all, I enabled metadata setting `--conf spark.es.read.metadata="true"`. Obviously my function doesn't flatten data from maps, just structs. The schema of my dataframe now looks something like:

```
root
 |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- field_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field_n: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _metadata: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

How can I extract only the `_id` key and related value from `_metadata` and add it to my `df`? (Removing also the `_metadata` itself, as I need only the `_id` field)

Comment: can you share a self contained example? your code is not reproducible as of now.

Comment: What is missing is some imports (I can add them), the point of the code is the data returned from ES with the `--conf spark.es.read.metadata="true"`. Returning any generic data from ES with that option will put in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, I found a barely acceptable workaround. Instead of getting `_id` from ES, I generate an UUID inside Spark creating the MD5 of a message. In this way you loose the matching between ES and Hadoop, but you can do some analysis on the assumption of UUID itself. I put this "partial" solution, as it may help some future googlers:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

val md5 = udf((string: String) => {MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(string.getBytes).map("%02X".format(_)).mkString + scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString })

df = df.withColumn("uuid",md5(col("message")))
```

I've also add some salt (a 10 characters random string) while generating the string, just to be sure to reduce nameclash if I'm unlucky enough to have the same log twice with the same timestamp.